# Stop fish spawning in a 1X1 block water tube

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I have a tube system which carries loot with packed ice on the bottom and water to push it around quickly. This works very efficiently however I am getting an excessive amount of fish and dolphins spawning inside of the tube which I think limits the tubes ability to carry loot as well as make the game a bit laggy. I want to know if there are any ways of stopping the fish from spawning in the tubes or killing them effecgtively whithout removing the packed ice from underneath. The top and sides of the tube are currently made from glass. I'm aware that mobs can't spawn on magma blocks however I don't want to switch my ice for this - will replacing the sides with magma help? (don't want to set that all up for it to then fail). I have also tried placing sea pickles on source blocks but that hasn't done anything.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answer, here are some other somewhat conditional options:

- You could consider moving the tube to a non-water biome, where
  aquatic mobs do not spawn.
- Assuming you are using single source blocks for the water tubes, you could try using a waterlogged fence or slab (item entities can pass on the side or underneath), which fish won't be able to spawn in.

If these don't work, it would be helpful to have some screenshots to get more context for your setup.

Comment: The setup was a guardian farm so moving to another biome wasn't really an option, the fence would let XP through but not the items i am fairly sure, however the slab should work. Just saying this for anyone else who may come across this post as this knowledge is now useless to me due to the world with the problems i was referencing to has since been corrupted and i doubt i will ever spend the time to rebuild a guardian farm

Answer (score -1):

Saw this on reddit, guy suggested to add kelp to the source blocks (or replace the block under water source with magma block). This isn't a proved solution and I really don't know what the system looks for while spawning fish

Comment: Hi x0xen0x, despite not knowing if this is indeed an answer, can you at least link to your source?